# Change the color of elements inside a Grid once a mouse hovers the Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I'm working on a WPF application. I have a button, which contains a Grid with a TextBlock and a Path element, as following:

```
<Button x:Name="btn"  Margin="1">
     <Button.Content>
          <Grid  Style="{DynamicResource button_special_hover}">
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tx" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{DynamicResource MenuString}" Grid.Column="2" />
                <Path x:Name="path" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource MarkerBrush}" Data="M 65.3334,41.3334C 65.3334,45.0133 62.3467,48 58.6667" Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
```

What I want to achieve is that once I hover the grid inside the button with my mouse, I want the foreground of the text inside the textblock to turn into white and the fill color for the path element to turn into white too.

What I've tried to do is declare a style for the grid as following: (button_special_hover)

```
<Style x:Key="button_special_hover" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                                           Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                                           Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I don't get what I want. Once I hover over the grid, nothing happens. Only when I hover the Textblock inside the grid, the text turns into White. Once I hover the Path, nothing happens.

How can I achieve that once I hover the grid both the textblock foreground and the Path Fill turn into White? Thanks!

Comment: *"hover the grid inside the button with my mouth"* -- can you disambiguate and explain that phrase? Are you using in your mouth in some way to hover a grid inside a button, or is your mouth contained in the button in some way, and you're hovering (transitively?) the grid inside that mouth-button?

Comment: Wait, do you actually mean "mouse", not "mouth"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you specified the fill on the path element.

NOTE: I 'fixed' the Data by added ",41.3334" to it.

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource MarkerBrush}" Data="M 65.3334,41.3334C 65.3334,45.0133 62.3467,48 58.6667,41.3334" Grid.Column="0" />
```

When you do that, you can't override it. If you specified it in the style instead then you'd get the results you want.

Remove Fill from Path:

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stretch="Fill" Data="M 65.3334,41.3334C 65.3334,45.0133 62.3467,48 58.6667,41.3334" Grid.Column="0" />
```

and add Fill to the style:

```
<Style x:Key="button_special_hover" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                                    Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},
                                    Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <!-- "All I did was add this line below" -->
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource MarkerBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now, most of my question is answered.
Now, I just need to figure out how to change the colors once I hover the Grid itself and not only when I hover the Textblock and path inside the Grid.

Comment: @DimaK - it's because the content of the button doesn't fill the button. If you set the button's  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" (default values are center) then it'll cover the entire inside of the button. If that makes the content of the button look weird then you may need adjust that xaml to make it look like you want it to. Otherwise, you could always adjust the button's control template.

Comment: @DimaK - just to explain a little more, it does change when you hover the grid but the grid doesn't cover the entire content space of the button. The grid is, essentially, auto sized inside of the button's content presenter. That's why it looks like you have to hover over the path or textblock. Add Background="Beige" to your grid's xaml and it should be very visible where the grid is in the button's content area.